# Does the solution to this ODE have a closed form?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following two initial value problems:

Problem 1: 
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\cos x}-\frac{y^2}{4}}, \ \ y(0)=-\sqrt{2}$

Problem 2:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\cos x}-\frac{y^2}{4}}+\frac{2}{5}y, \ \ y(\frac{\pi}{4})=-\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}$.

I put problem 1 into Mathematica with the following command: 
DSolve[{y'[x]==Sqrt[1/(2Cos[x])-y[x]^2/4],y[0]==-Sqrt[2]},y,x] , 
but Mathematica is unable to find the solution explicitly. But actually, the problem has an explicit solution: it is $y(x)=-\sqrt{2\cos x}$.

I am wondering if problem 2 has an explicit solution. 
Thanks!